# Other type of "hadronization" if the electroweak force would be stronger?

Tags: standard-model, electroweak, hadronization

Let's suppose that we have no symmetry breaking and the electroweak bosons remain massless (the W, Z and the photon). Let's also suppose that the coupling constants of SU(2) and U(1) are of the order of SU(3) of QCD. We know, that the Lagrangian has the kinetic "Maxwell" tensors for each vector boson (here I add just the SU(2)xU(1) part):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{kin} = - \frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{4} \textbf{G}^{\mu \nu}\textbf{G}_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}

SU(2) is, as SU(3) a non-abelian group and this leads to a self-coupling of the vector bosons if we expand $ - \frac{1}{4} \textbf{G}^{\mu \nu}\textbf{G}_{\mu \nu} $

So, when we assume massless vector bosons (or a very small mass is also possible, so that the boson propagator is not "small" for smaller $ q^2 $) and a higher coupling strength, could there be other types of "hadrons" or even coupled lepton systems like in the case of QCD, but with the electroweak bosons as the "glue"?

Comment: Of course there would be confined states for massless gauge bosons.  Naturally,   the very definition of EM would be moot, without SSB. But you might enjoy studying [Abbott-Farhi models](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90580-0)... What is the question?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I will have a look at it. I was asking, because maybe, after higher order calculations it could be the case, that confined electroweak states in the massless limit could be very improbable and QCD will always "win" and hadronize as we know it in the real world.